# Python, re.match with regex

Tags: python

I have a code where I am trying to match strings. My regex may be wrong or it could be my `re_year` not being read in properly.

code:

```
Fiscal_Year = 2023
re_year    = re.compile(f'^StackOverFlow-{Fiscal_Year}-\d+$')


for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    # Ensure it's for the current Fiscal_Year
    if not re.match(re_year, row.Folder_Name_to_create):
        print(re_year)
        print(row.Folder_Name_to_create)
        print('Skipping request out-of-year:', row.Folder_Name_to_create)
        df.loc[idx, 'status'] = 'out-of-year'
        continue
```

What re_year is: `re.compile('^StackOverFlow-2023-\\d+$')`
sample df record:   `StackOverFlow-2023-0704-2225--`
Edit - Not all my records end with `--`, it could end in letters, brackets, numbers, etc.

All my requests are being skipped.

Why is my `re.match` not working here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sample record ends with `'--'`, and your regex requires string to end with digits.

Comment: I should have nentioned, all my records do not end in `--`. It could end in anything,  letters, brackets, etc.

Comment: Well, your `'\d+$'` requires a string that ends in one or more digits.

Answer (score 1):

Your re is wrong. It would match something like `StackOverFlow-2023-0704` but not if the second group number repeats do

`re.compile(f'^StackOverFlow-{Fiscal_Year}[-\d+]+$')`

Also your string ends with '-' not digits. Add that to the end of the regex using  '-*' if you want 0 or more times, '-+' for 1 or more times or even '--' if exactly two

For a full answer of

`re.compile(f'^StackOverFlow-{Fiscal_Year}[-\d+]+-*$')`

Comment: I should have mentioned, all my records do not end in --. It is possible it could end in anything, letters, brackets, numbers, etc.

Comment: re.compile(f'^StackOverFlow-{Fiscal_Year}[-\d+]+.*$')